# Issue with setting things equal to nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, game-engine

I'm working on a text-based RPG to keep up my programming knowledge over the summer (I've taken 2 trimesters of C++ so far).

Anyways, I've been working on the character's inventory system, and I've run into an issue. The inventory is an array of type `Item` (which I've already made). The default constructor for `Item` sets it to be a "Plain Rock", but I just want the inventory to be completely empty when it is created. So I thought of a workaround. When creating the inventory, setting the address of every spot in the inventory to equal `nullptr`:

```
Inventory::Inventory()
{
    currentBPSize = 5;
    backpack = new Item[MAX_BACKPACK_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_BACKPACK_SIZE; i++){
        &backpack[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Whenever, I run this, I get an error

> lvalue required as the left operand of the assignment

What am I doing wrong, or is there something I should be doing completely different?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `&backpack[i] = nullptr;` to do? You haven't created an array of pointers, so you can't set each element of the array to be `nullptr`, or any other flavour of pointer.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to use a `nullptr` this way, even if it did compile.

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Problem solved. More problems solved than you asked.

Comment: @PasserBy That can grow beyond `MAX_BACKPACK_SIZE`, which I assume is relatively small. A fixed-size array makes sense here.

Comment: @DanielH But using a `std::array` or raw array, you'll need to also separately track how many slots are currently in use, creating more opportunities for errors. Any performance benefit from eliminating a heap allocation would be premature optimization.

Comment: @aschepler I suppose it depends on other details. With the options suggested in ArrHare’s answer, a fixed size is appropriate; if you just want a container of `Item`s which can’t be empty, a `vector` is better as long as you always check the size when adding new elements. The difference comes from whether it makes sense to have slot 2 empty but not slot 3; for a graphical game or one where the player might access items by index, you might want to be able to have empty slots.

Comment: If by-index access isn’t needed, [`boost::container::static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html) still has better semantics because it makes it clear a maximum size is desired. It might still be an issue to remove from the middle, but there are a couple ways to handle that (including “ignore that it’s a bit slower than necessary because at the relevant sizes the effect is negligible”, probably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `&backpack[i]`, the compiler creates a temporary `const` value that represents the address of `backpack[i]`.  That's the value that it then attempts to assign `nullptr` to.  Since the compiler-created temporary value is const (the address of `backpack[i]` ain't changing), then the compiler barfs at your attempt to assign to it.

Since `backpack` is an array of objects, you can't set them to null either.

If I were making your game and I assume your design is that your backpack has a fixed number of slots, I'd do one of the below:

- Create a "Free Slot" item type, and have that be the default constructed item.  When the user changes the contents of their backpack, then you'd modify the `Item` that is already there.  This would be the smallest modification to your design, but probably not great in the long run (your copy constructor would have to be perfect when adding things).
- Or Make your array an array of `Item*` (pointers to `Item`), and then they'd be nullable.  This would require more memory management however.
- Even better, I'd probably make it an array of `shared_ptr<Item>`, so that I didn't have to worry quite as much about memory management.

As one of the other commenters said, I'd recommend using `std::vector` instead of a raw array as well, unless the exercise is to just learn more about arrays and memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to give that "Free Slot" method a try.

Comment: I would recommend `std::optional<Item>` instead of any type of pointer, and `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_pointer` because there isn't shared ownership (you can move an item from the inventory to the bank; it doesn’t make sense for it to be in both and keep existing unless removed from both).